# Not able to install redmine properly. Showing index and dpkg error

Tags: server, redmine

I am trying to install Redmine in my ubuntu 14.04 server. It is installed but when run in the browser it shows only the index and not the home page. When I try to fix the bug it shows

```
dpkg: error processing package redmine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I try to update the machine it shows

```
W: GPG error: https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty Release: The following 
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3p484 PHP 5.5.9-1 Apache/2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Looks like a certificate problem with the phusion server. Not sure.

I used [this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_25x_on_Ubuntu_1404_with_Apache2_Phusion_Passenger_MySQL_and_Subversion) and after this error message I kept going with the installation.

In the end i just typed the following command:
`gem install passenger`

and it worked.

Comment: I had done the same, but it did not work. Still struggling.
I still get the index page  and nothing else. Rake aborts each time I try to generate the secret token. I have no clue of how to get the login page.